# Drupal 7 - Cors

Tags: 7, http-request

I'm trying to get a hang of the CORS requests.

I'm logged in at the website, this is done manually from the website.
Now I'm trying to fetch my own user data from another website.

I have the "fetch token" request up and running just fine.

But when I try to fetch the user data I always get the anonymous user data.

Here is my Drupal Code:

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
  drupal_add_http_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], TRUE);
  drupal_add_http_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true", TRUE);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    drupal_add_http_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS", TRUE);

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
    drupal_add_http_header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'],
      TRUE
    );
  }
  drupal_exit();
  exit;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  global $user;
  netpunkt_provider_remove_user_data($user);

  $return = new stdClass();
  $return->sessid = session_id();
  $return->session_name = session_name();
  $return->user = $user;

  drupal_json_output($return);
  drupal_exit();
  exit;
}
```

Here is my javascript code from the other website:

```
 var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
      // Most browsers.
      xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined") {
      // IE8 & IE9
      xhr = new XDomainRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
      // CORS not supported.
      xhr = null;
    }
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    return xhr;
  };

  function tokenButton() {

    var token = "";

    var url = 'http://******/cors_token';
    var method = 'POST';
    var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        token = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).token;
        document.getElementById("userButton").setAttribute("token", token);
        document.getElementById("tokenSpan").innerHTML = token;
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function(data) {
      alert('FEJL');
      console.log(data);
    };

    xhr.send();
  }

  function userButton() {

    var url = 'http://******/cors_check';
    var method = 'POST';
    var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "X-CSRF-Token",
        document.getElementById("userButton").getAttribute("token")
    );

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    };

    xhr.send();
  }

  document.getElementById("tokenButton").addEventListener(
    "click", tokenButton
  );

  document.getElementById("userButton").addEventListener(
    "click", userButton
  );
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is...

My Firefox had "Accept third party cookies" set to "Never".

I changed this to "Always" - and Voila - the script now works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in *_drupal_session_read()*.

```
if (empty($sid) || !isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !isset($_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name])) {
$user = drupal_anonymous_user();
return '';
```

Since the cors request runs on it's own request, there's no session info, hence you get the anonymous users data.

Comment: Hi Krisztián, I'm not sure I'm following you. I have "allow credential" in the request - so it should be allowed to read cookies (Or am I missing something in your answer?)

Comment: You are running a request from an other host. The cookies are stored in your browser. If a session is being started for that request, it will have it's on session data. If you would like to get a list of logged in users, run a query against the session table and grab the uids.

Comment: It is my own user data I want from another site. I logon to site A, go on to site B. Site B now needs to verify that I'm logged in at site A. Thank you for your time / help btw :-)